# returning a non serializer field otp in django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, response

I am trying to return otp to my response alongwith other serializer data. but as it is not submitted through request i am unable to understand how to give it in response. OTP is getting stored with other data in the user table perfectly but I am facing problem only  in returning it in response .my code is given below:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    otp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
  password_confirmation = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)


  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
    instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
    if password is not None:
        instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
    instance.otp = randint(1, 98787)
    instance.save()
    return instance

  def otp(self):
    instance = self.Meta.model()
    return instance.otp
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def user_signup(request):
serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    content = {'user': serializer.data, 'otp': UserSerializer.otp()}
    return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `serializer.save()` return instance you can do following:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    instance = serializer.save()
    content = {'user': serializer.data, 'otp': instance .otp}
```

So `def otp(self)` in `UserSerializer` is not required.

Comment: @RishabhPandey you are welcome! You can accept my answer if it was helpful.